# add() argument after * must be a sequence, not Settings

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, addition

I'm trying to build a game that moves a ship left and right with the arrow keys and fires bullets when the spacebar is pressed. When I press the spacebar my game crashes and this error is shown:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
TypeError: add() argument after * must be a sequence, not Settings
```

Here's my code:

```
class Settings():
    """A class to store all settings for Alien Invasion."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game's settings."""
        # Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 800
        self.screen_height = 480
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

        # Ship settings 
        self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5

        # Bullet settings
        self.bullet_speed_factor = 1
        self.bullet_width = 3
        self.bullet_height = 15
        self.bullet_color = 60, 60, 60

import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Bullet(Sprite):
    """A class to manage bullets fired from the ship"""

    def _init__(self, ai_settings, screen, ship):
        """Create a bullet object at the ship's current position."""
        super(Bullet, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen

        # Create a bullet rect at (0, 0) and then set correct position.
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, ai_settings.bullet_width, ai_settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
        self.rect.top = ship.rect.top

        # Store the bullet's position as a decimal value.
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

        self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
        self.speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor

    def update(self):
        """Move the bullet up the screen"""
        # Update the decimal position of the bullet.
        self.y -= self.speed_factor
        # Update the rect position.
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def draw_bullet(self):
        """Draw the bullet to the screen."""
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)

import sys

import pygame

from bullet import Bullet

def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Respond to keypresses."""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        # Create a new bullet and add it to the bullets group.
        new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
        bullets.add(new_bullet)

def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    """Respind to key releases."""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False


def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ship)
```

And finally the main file:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    # Initialize pygame, settings, and screen object.
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    # Make a ship.
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
    # Make a group to store bullets in.
    bullets = Group()

    # Start the main loop for the game.
    while True:

        # Watch the keyboard and mouse events.
        gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        ship.update()
        bullets.update()
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)

run_game()
```

The trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\martin\Desktop\python_work\alien_invasion\alien_invasion.py", line 30, in <module>
    run_game()
  File "C:\Users\martin\Desktop\python_work\alien_invasion\alien_invasion.py", line 25, in run_game
    gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
  File "C:\Users\martin\Desktop\python_work\alien_invasion\game_functions.py", line 33, in check_events
    check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
  File "C:\Users\martin\Desktop\python_work\alien_invasion\game_functions.py", line 15, in check_keydown_events
    new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
  File "C:\Users\martin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.add(*groups)
  File "C:\Users\martin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 142, in add
    self.add(*group)
TypeError: add() argument after * must be a sequence, not Settings
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Jokab is right, you forgot the extra underscore. However, for future practice it is important to learn to read the Python `TrackBack`. It usually gives you a good idea of where the problem is. For example, take the `TrackBack` you pasted here. Python first tells you it had a problem running `run_game()`. So python then says that **in** your game running function it has a problem calling the method `gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)`. It then looked at your initialization of the bullet class `new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship` and has a problem with it. And in the very next line is were it gives the `TypeError`. Now, while you could figure out exactly what python is saying about the `TypeError`, which is a viable option. But just from looking at it you could determine that it has a problem adding your bullet object to the sprites group. Which means that if I were you, I'd start my searching in the `Bullet` class. And sure enough there is a typo in your `__init__` function.

While it is not the end of the world if you don't learn how to read python `TrackBack`'s, It will save you plenty of time in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an underscore `_` in your `Bullet.__init__` method. You currently have `_init__` when it should be `__init__`.

This results in Python calling the `Sprite.__init__` method with `ai_settings` as the first argument, since it cannot find any overridden `__init__` for `Bullet`. That leads to problems.

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Comment: @MartinDimitrov Consider accepting this answer if it helped you. :)